# Mixing Plotly/ipywidgets to modify the x axis of a scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, ipywidgets

I want to mix Plotly with a dropdown widget, the idea being to make some scatter plots and modify the x axis through the widget. Let's say that my dataset is the following :

```
import sea born as sns
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
```

And my target is the column `carat`. What I tried so far is to create the scatters, include them into the widget and display it :

```
predictors = df.columns.tolist()
predictors.remove("carat")
target = df["carat"]

data = []
for predictor in predictors:
    chart = go.Scatter(x = df[predictor],
                  y = target,
                  mode="markers")
    fig = go.Figure(data=chart)
    data.append((predictor,fig))

widgets.Dropdown(options = [item[0] for item in data],
                       value = [item[0] for item in data][0],
                       description = "Select :",
                       disabled=False)
```

Yet, I am new to ipywidgets/plotly and don't understand what is not working here, since it displays the widget but not the charts even when I change its value. How can I modify the code so that it finally displays the charts when selecting a predictor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [interact](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) to read the values from the DropDown and plot your graph:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from ipywidgets import widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
import plotly.express as px

df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
predictors = df.columns.tolist()
predictors.remove("carat")
target = df["carat"]

@interact
def read_values(
    predictor=widgets.Dropdown(
        description="Select :", value="clarity", options=predictors
    )
):

    fig = px.scatter(df, x = predictor, y = target)
    go.FigureWidget(fig.to_dict()).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Current version of the code gives `NameError: name 'px' is not defined`. Shouldn't it be something more like `fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x = df[predictor], y = target))`? Although that doesn't quite give what you show.

Comment: @Wayne, thanks for pointing that out, I only added `import plotly.express as px`, it works seamlessly right now :)

Comment: That'll work. The example I was adapting your approach to was using graph objects so what I suggested illustrates you can use `fig = go.Figure(` too.

Comment: @Wayne, I think it will work, please give it a try.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Yes, what you have now works seamlessly now. I was trying to say that plus add saying that the example I was adapting to was trying not to use Plotly express so I was trying to stick with just Ploty graph objects, which works, too.